# EXTCODESIZE returning 32 for contract size less than 32

Tags: solidity, assembly, bytes, create2, create

I'm currently completing the Ethernaut challenges, one of them is to deploy a small contract (runtime bytecode is 10 bytes long).

I'm running the tests on my local machine, and using Solidity to deploy the contract.

I'm using the `CREATE` opcode to deploy the bytecode, which I have explicitly defined in the contract. The results are the same for `CREATE2`.

When I use `EXTCODESIZE` to get back the contract code size for my deployed contract, it is returning `32`, when the runtime bytecode size is for sure 10 (with initialization bytecode the size is `22`).

My code:

```
    function Deploy() public returns(uint) {
        bytes memory code = "\x60\x0a\x60\x0c\x60\x00\x39\x60\x20\x60\x00\xf3\x60\x42\x60\x80\x52\x60\x20\x60\x80\xf3";

        address addr;
        uint size;
        assembly {
          addr := create(0, add(code, 0x20), mload(code))
          size := extcodesize(addr)
          if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
            revert(0, 0)
          }
        }
        return size;
    }
```

Why is it returning 32? I know this is the min word size but I am not padding the `code` input with zeros. However, the returned result (via `EXTCODECOPY`) is padded with zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is returning 32 because your deployement bytecode explicitely return 32 bytes.

Breaking it down :

> \x60\x0a\x60\x0c\x60\x00\x39\x60\x20\x60\x00\xf3

- PUSH 0x0a : length to copy (runtime bytecode is 10 bytes long)
- PUSH 0x0c : source offset (runtime bytecode starts at the 12th byte)
- PUSH 0x00 : destination offset (copy at memory address 0x00 and up)
- [CODECOPY](https://ethervm.io/#39)  : perform the actual copy
- PUSH 0x20 : length to return **<-- Here is your mistake**
- PUSH 0x00 : source address of return
- RETURN : return 0x20 bytes starting at address 0x00

You just copied 0x0a bytes, but you are returning 0x20. Simply change the faulty PUSH 0x20 (0x60 0x20) of the deployement bytecode to a PUSH 0x0a (0x60 0x0a)and you will see the expected contract size of 10.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Yes that solved it, my bad, thank you !